# same algorithm execution time on different computers?

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

if an algorithm with O(nlogn) time complexity is executed in two seconds on a computer ,how long does it take a 100 times faster computer to execute the same algorithm? is it 2/100 seconds? as far as i know Big o notation is a function of the input size and has nothing to do with execution time of the same algorithm on different computers, am i right?

Comment: This question cannot be answered. It depends on a lot of factors. Some examples are: Is the RAM also 100 times faster? Is the algorithm using IO? What is the size of the Cache on both machines? Is the algorithm optimized for the "slower" machine?

Comment: Lack of knowledge does not constitute a reason for downvoting incomers posts. It may drive neophytes away from the community. There is no official threshold on what incomers should know before joining stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity does not say anything about the running time.

**Example**: I'm working on a very complex algorithm in a small team and the exact same algorithm runs in 30 minutes on my computer, in 60 minutes on a computer (similar performance as my comuter) of a team member, in 15 minutes on a netbook with a very slow processor but a different OS and a special extension. The runningtime also differs by different compilers.

The complexity gives you only a hint, how much more time your algorithm needs, if the input grows.

Comment: What if the two computers are exactly the same except the processor speed?

Comment: If I run the exact same code compiled by a team member it is slower as when I compile it myself. So no, even if you ran the code on the same computer but compile it somwhere else, it has a different running time.